# Encountered trouble with PHP SQL Database Edit and Delete

Tags: php, sql, database, edit

The following is the page for listing the database which works fine

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_user = 'yeospace_nm0102'; 
$db_pass = '*********'; 
$db_name = 'yeospace_nm0102'; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM AddEntry';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM AddEntry ORDER BY id DESC"); 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List Of Reviews</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Reviews</h1>
    <table class="data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NO</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Review</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$no."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</td>";  
            echo "<td>".$row['age']."</td>";  
            echo "<td>".$row['review']."</td>";     
            echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";    

            $no++;
        }
?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
<button onClick="location.href='index.php'"> Return to Home</button>

</body>
</html>
```

However I encountered problems when I tried to delete and edit. Nothing was deleted and nothing was edited.

This is my delete.php

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_user = 'yeospace_nm0102'; 
$db_pass = '***********'; 
$db_name = 'yeospace_nm0102'; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM AddEntry';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM AddEntry WHERE id=$id");

header("Location:ListEntry.php");
?>
```

And this is my update.php (which does the editing and saving it)

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_user = 'yeospace_nm0102'; 
$db_pass = '********'; 
$db_name = 'yeospace_nm0102'; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM AddEntry';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $author=$_POST['author'];
    $title=$_POST['title']; 
    $review=$_POST['review'];    


    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE AddEntry SET author='$author',title='$title', review='$review' WHERE id=$id");

    header("Location: ListEntry.php");
}
?>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM AddEntry WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $author = $res['author'];
    $title = $res['title'];
    $review = $res['review'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Edit Reviews</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="ListEntry.php">Home</a>
    <br/><br/>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $author;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Review:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="review" value="<?php echo $review;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to troubleshoot the whole night but I can't find where the error is among these 3 files. Can someone help me please? Thanks alot !

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: What purpose does the `SELECT * FROM AddEntry` serve in either of these script fragments?

Comment: How many rows are there in the `AddEntry` table?

Comment: @RiggsFolly there are 7 rows in AddEntry

Comment: Would it be better to delete the css from the question

Comment: If you need help learning how to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for safe and secure queries, then you can check out [this answer that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514591/5827005) that demonstrates a function that I wrote that makes [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) **easy**, **clean**, and **secure**. Alternatively you should learn how to use [Prepared Statements for MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I would but for this project my lecturer insists on mysqli so yeah.

Comment: @KelvinHow That's fine, then use [Prepared Statements for MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) - unless your lecturer also insists on teaching horrible and insecure coding practices? In which case I would stop being lectured by them if possible.

Comment: If your prof has an example site, hit it with `hissite.com/update.php?id=1%3BDROP%20TABLE%20users%3B` Perhaps he won't shy away from parameterization after that. As for your issue, can you have it print out the SQL statements that are being generated for your UPDATE and DELETE. You can confirm that the values are coming through as expected and run them manually in a mysql client like phpmyadmin or whatever.

Comment: Apparently unused and using a non-existant connection `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); `

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi thanks for pointing out the mistake, however I have changed the 'users' to my table name, 'AddEntry' but yet still nothing works.

Comment: `mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id");` instead of that you should be using `mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id");` in both pages replace `$mysqli` to `$conn`

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid Hi I have changed $mysqli to $conn, but I still cannot delete or edit. The codes above have been updated please help me see if I have missed out anything or should change anything. Thanks alot !

Comment: Are  you getting any error..???

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid No I am not getting any error, I just cannot edit or delete. Like after I press delete, it prompts the user to confirm, and click OK, it refreshes the page (ListEntry.php) but the data is still there and is still in the database. Same goes for the edit.

Comment: put an echo and die at your delete and update pages to check if they are being called.

Comment: Thanks you everyone for your inputs, I have solved the issue. Apparently my $id was wrong because it was capitalized $ID in my database hence I can't edit or delete. Still once again thanks everyone. Ok can someone help me mark this question as answered or close this question thanks!